# NullPointer Exception: Using PageFactory Design Pattern for Appium

Tags: nullpointerexception, appium

I am trying to use PageFactory Design Pattern but getting Null Pointer Exception.Please suggest any improvement required.

My Sample code looks like:

```
public DriverCapabilities() throws IOException{
    URL url;
    try {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "90");
        caps.setCapability("browserName", "");

            caps.setCapability("appActivity",Config.appActivity );
            caps.setCapability("appPackage", Config.appPackage);
            caps.setCapability("appWaitActivity",Config.appWaitActivity);
            caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
            caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        }

        caps.setCapability("app", Config.path);
        caps.setCapability("appium-version", "1.3.7.2");
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        innerDriver = Config.os.equalsIgnoreCase("ANDROID")? new AndroidDriver(url, caps): new IOSDriver(url, caps);
        DriverWait.implicitWait();
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(innerDriver, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
    }
```

Sample Screen Class:

```
public class DemoScreen{
@AndroidFindBy(id = "eula_accept")
private static RemoteWebElement eula;
public static void submit() throws IOException{
     init.getInstance(); //To initialize the driver
     getEula().click();
}
public static WebElement getEula() {
    return eula;
}
}
```

Sample Test code:

```
public class Demo1{
@Test(groups={"smokeTest"})
public void test1() throws IOException {
DemoScreen.submit();
}*
```

Is it because somewhere I'm not initializing the object or has it to do with the design pattern I'm following?

Comment: Where you get the NPE?

Comment: NPE? Sorry, Didn't get u

Comment: NPE is a synonym for `NullPointerException`. You should mark the line where  the exception is thrown. Or better add the stacktrace.

Comment: While trying to click on eula element. @getEula.click() event

Comment: Was able to initialize AppiumDriver. After that when tried to click on the element it is throwing NPE